# Sort varchar as number when it can also be a mix of numbers and letters

Tags: sql, varchar

The following sorts CustomerNo in the following order: (1,2,3,10,20,400), which is what is intended. But I get an error when inserting a non-numerical CustomerNo, such as 1a. the problem is the WHERE clause, where CustomerNo > 1.

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1a' to data type int.
```

I don't particulary care where non-numerical CustomerNo's are placed in the order. I just don't want it to fail. If I remove the WHERE clause, I always get the order (1,2,3,10,20,400, 1a), but then with the SELECT TOP 1 *, I always get the row where CustomerNo=1. I would like to get the next one.

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM [Database].[Company].[Table]
WHERE CompanyNo = 804
  AND CustomerNo > 1
ORDER BY 
  CASE IsNumeric(CustomerNo) 
    WHEN 1 THEN Replicate('0', 100 - Len(CustomerNo)) + CustomerNo 
    ELSE CustomerNo
  END
```

Comment: What RDBMS is it? I have done it for SQL Server

Comment: Tbh, I don't see why you would want to do this, but if the > 1 condition is more or less set in stone you can change the WHERE clause to: CompanyNo = 804 and CustomerNo <> '1'...

Comment: Anton, sorry. It is me not being clear. I basically want to select the next or previous row. The records are being displayed in a window and there are buttons to select the next and previous record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I did it (adjust it to your column length):

```
CASE IsNumeric(site_id) WHEN 1 THEN REPLACE(STR(site_id, 8, 0), ' ', '0') ELSE site_id END
```